# Defining Agenda Time Frame

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

Org-agenda has been working well all week. Now that it is Sunday, `C-c a a` produces an agenda that displays Monday 18 November through Saturday 23 of November.

I've changed some of the relevant parameters as below

```
(setq org-agenda-span 10)
(setq org-agenda-start-day "-3d")
```

or

```
(setq org-agenda-start-day "-1d")
(setq org-agenda-span 5)
(setq org-agenda-start-on-weekday nil)
```

But it hasn't gotten the agenda to display days beyond Saturday the 23rd of Nov.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did not have to do with the time frame I was specifiying.

Instead it was a problem while parsing the .org files I includin agenda. A message was raised, `habit "Weekly Review has no scheduled repeat period or has na incorrect one."

Initially I ignored this while trying to debug the agenda problems but when I set `SCHEDULED: <2019-11-17 Sun ++1d>` correctly, the agenda built correctly.